# Ошибка при генерации случайных чисел

Tags: c++, c++11, случайные-числа

Пытаюсь сделать рандом, используя c++11. Делаю так:

```
random_device rd; 
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_int_distribution <> dis(1, 274876858367);
__int64 s=dis(gen);
```

Выдает ошибку на строчке: `uniform_int_distribution`. Ошибка:

> invalid min and max arguments for uniform_int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну еще бы... Вы же задаете ему параметр, явно выпадающий за пределы `int`...

Попробуйте так:

```
uniform_int_distribution <unsigned long long> dis(1, 274876858367ull);
```